# Ruby alias method chain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class like this

```
class Foo
   attr_accessor :name
end

f = Foo.new
f.name = "bar"
```

and I would like it to respond to the following method chain with the name attribute so that it interfaces with another object

```
f.baz.name == f.name
```

Is there an easy way to return this?

Comment: Do you need to do this more than once in your program?  And do you need more levels of indirection, such as `foo.baz.qux.name == foo.name`?

Comment: I'm curious, why would you want to do something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

class Foo

  attr_accessor :name

  def baz
    self
  end

end

foo = Foo.new
foo.name = 'Fred'
p [foo.name, foo.baz.name]    # => ["Fred", "Fred"]
foo.baz.name = 'Barney'
p [foo.name, foo.baz.name]    # => ["Barney", "Barney"]
```

Comment: Thanks Wayne! I feel pretty dumb for not thinking of that.